# Set detailtextlabel of static cell programmatically

Tags: uitableview, static, tableview, cell, detailtextlabel

I have a tableView with a few sections and I have it set for static cells instead of dynamic prototypes. The problem is that I can't set the detail text label of a static cell programmatically or at least I don't know how. Is it possible ? The only way I see of doing this is having dynamic prototypes which means I'm going to have to deal with setting up all the cell.textLabels in my dataSource and also all the sections and my segues will not work anymore. If anyone has ideas it would be great help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `UITableView` is in a `UITableViewController`, here are 2 approaches that are useful:

**Custom** `UITableViewCell`: In the view controller class, declare a property for a label as: `@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelInCell;`

In the storyboard, drag a `UILabel` into the cell, select the controller's *Connections Inspector*, and connect the outlet of the property by dragging from the inspector to the `UILabel` object.

You can then assign the label text programmatically, for example, in `viewDidLoad:` of the controller class.

**Standard datasource**: Alternatively, you can implement just one method: - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in the view controller's datasource and set the `detailTextLabel` property there.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I realized that it is possible to subclass UITableViewController without implementing `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
That way all the static cells defined in Interface Builder appear as set up and I can set an outlet to my special cell that I want to configure in `- (void)ViewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: The comment by Scottocs was most appreciated!!  I was working with the static cells for hours, and I was just worried that I'm double layering two labels on top of one another, one being the new one that I'd be adding and the other the titlelable of the cell. But it all makes sense now:):)